# Multiple Private WebSocket Messages with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket

I am using Spring @RequestMapping for REST synchronous services consuming and producing JSON. I now want to add asynchronous responses were the client sends a list of ids and the server sends back the details as it gets them to only that one client.

I been searching a while and have not found what I am looking for. I have seen two different approaches for Spring. The most common is a message broker approach where it appears that everybody gets every message by subscribing to a queue or topic. This is VERY unacceptable since this is private data. I also have a finite number of data points to return. The other approach is a Callable, AsyncResult or DeferredResult. This appears to keep the data private but I want to send multiple responses.

I have seen something similar to what I want but is uses [Jersey SSE](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html) on the server. I would like to stick with Spring.

This is what I currently have using pseudo code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/balances", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public GetAccountBalancesResponse getAccountBalances(@RequestBody GetAccountBalancesRequest request) {
  GetAccountBalancesResponse ret = new GetAccountBalancesResponse();

  ret.setBalances(synchronousService.getBalances(request.getIds());

  return ret;
}
```

This is what I am looking to do. It is rather rough since I have no clue of the details. Once I figure out sending I will work on the asynchronous part but would take any suggestions.

```
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/balances", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ???<BalanceDetails> getAccountBalances(@RequestBody GetAccountBalancesRequest request) {
  final ???<BalanceDetails> ret = new ???<>();

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      List<Future<BalanceDetails>> futures = asynchronousService.getBalances(request.getIds());

      while(!stillWaiting(futures)) {
        // Probably use something like a Condition to block until there is some details.
        ret.send(getFinishedDetails(futures));
      }

      ret.close();
    }
  }).start();

  return ret;
}
```

Thanks, Wes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a lot of digging but it looks like Spring Web 4.2 does support server side events. I was using Spring Boot 1.2.7 that uses Spring Web 4.1.7. Switching to Spring Boot 1.3.0.RC1 adds the SseEmitter.

Here is my pseudo code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/getAccountBalances", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter getAccountBalances(@QueryParam("accountId") Integer[] accountIds) {
  final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

  new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < ids.length; xx++) {
          Thread.sleep(2000L + rand.nextInt(2000));

          BalanceDetails balance = new BalanceDetails();
          ...
          emitter.send(emitter.event().name("accountBalance").id(String.valueOf(accountIds[xx]))
                  .data(balance, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }

        emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("complete").data("complete"));
        emitter.complete();
      } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
        emitter.completeWithError(ee);
      }
    }
  }).start();

  return emitter;
}
```

Still working out closing the channel gracefully and parsing the JSON object using Jersey EventSource but it is a lot better than a message bus.

Also spawning a new thread and using a sleep are just for the POC. I wouldn't need either since we already have an asynchronous process to access a slow back end system.

Wes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this: you are using plain Spring actions, which are intended to be processed in a single thread that possilby blocks until the full request is computed. You don't create threads inside controllers - or at least not in that way.

If the computation lasts really long and you want to give your users a visual feedback, these are the steps:

- optimize the procedure :) use indices, caching, whatever
- if still isn't enough, the computation still lasts forever and users demand feedback, you'll have two options

  - poll with javascript and show a visual feedback (easier). Basically you submit the task to a thread pool and return immediately, and there's another controller method that reads the current state of the computation and returns it to the user. This method is called by javascript every 10 seconds or so
  - use a backchannel (server push, [websocket](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)) - not so easy because you have to implement both the client and the server part. Obviously there are libraries and protocols that will make this only a handful lines of code long, but if you have never tried it before, you'll spend some time understanding the setup - plus debugging websockets is not as easy as regular HTTP because of the debugging tools

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use websockets and all I see is message bus/broadcast examples for Spring. I added posting a RequestBody to show that I want to receive a payload. I added the thread to show that I want an asynchronous process that returns multiple responses. I have only found Jersey examples that match what I am trying to do or Spring examples that returns only 1 asynchronous response.
I have no control over how long the data takes as it comes from remote back end systems that are out of my control. I also have not control on how much data since that is user dependent.

Comment: Let me rephrase: websockets are a technology for server push. If you need it, you also need a server side message bus that clients register with. From your comment it seems you have no control, no constraint and no requirement. I wonder how you can write any code...

Comment: Also, take a look at [`MessageBrokerRegistry.setUserPrefix`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/MessageBrokerRegistry.html#setUserDestinationPrefix-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I have a very clear requirement that does not match the concept of a message bus that the client subscribes to. When I get the request, I know which data items I will be returning. What I don't know is how long it will take to retrieve the data item so I want to use websockets to push the data as I get it. That is the problem I am having with the Spring implementation; it has tried to hide the complexity but seems to have hidden the flexibility too.

Comment: Well, you **need** a message bus - otherwise, how would you dispatch the *It's ready!* event?